Why is there no Betz law in reverse?
Betz's law says that only 16/27 of the power in a wind stream can be converted into electrical power by a wind turbine. However, it appears that 100% of the power supplied to a fan motor can be converted into the power in a wind stream. Why is that? Or perhaps I am mistaken?

This doesn't appear to be a question about aviation as defined in the [help], but it might make a good question on [physics.se]

This is an excellent aerospace engineering question.  Over in Physics, they've probably never heard of it.  Betz's law is a really interesting consequence of the conservation of mass and momentum for a non-ducted turbine.  First, there are three velocities at play, far upstream of the turbine (largest) at the turbine, and far downstream of the turbine (smallest).  As it turns out, the velocity at the turbine is the average of the upstream and downstream velocities.  The power extracted is related to the overall change in velocity, but also the mass flow through the turbine.

As you vary the load (thrust/drag force) on the turbine, you change the velocity at the turbine, but since mass flow is rhovA (constant at all three locations) you also change the amount of mass flow captured.  As often happens in engineering, there are two effects -- the overall delta V, but also the size of the captured streamtube.  When these come together, they form an equation with a distinct maximum.

For a propeller, we can add as much power as we want -- and we are not normalizing it by the power contained in the streamtube ahead of the propeller as a reference.

I've voted to reopen since this is a question about aerodynamics as also @RobMcDonald highlighted

Betz's law is a really interesting consequence of the conservation of mass and momentum for a non-ducted turbine. First, there are three velocities at play, far upstream of the turbine (largest) at the turbine, and far downstream of the turbine (smallest). As it turns out, the velocity at the turbine is the average of the upstream and downstream velocities. The power extracted is related to the overall change in velocity, but also the mass flow through the turbine.
The Wikipedia article has a nice derivation of this, if it doesn't make sense to you, I can try to walk through it.
As you vary the load (thrust/drag force) on the turbine, you change the velocity at the turbine, but since mass flow is rhovA (constant at all three locations) you also change the amount of mass flow captured. As often happens in engineering, there are two effects -- the overall delta V, but also the size of the captured streamtube. When these come together, they form an equation with a distinct maximum.
For a propeller, we can add as much power as we want -- and we are not normalizing it by the power contained in the streamtube ahead of the propeller as a reference.
